# SQL get sum of timestamp intervals

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have rows in my POSTGRESQL database like this:

[image]

I want to sum all timestamp intervals, where `power_draw_mode_id` = 2. It mean I want to get sum of (to_date - from_date) of of row 1 and 3.

Expected value in this example is 9 (hours).

Can someone help me how to do that?

Comment: What if there are other rows with id = 2?

Comment: I want to sum them all.

Comment: sum the difference between alternating rows?

Answer (score 1):

Is it what you want ? :

```
 select sum(to_date-from_date) from your_table where power_draw_mode_id=2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following.  It will give you the sum of the difference between to_date & from_date in hours:

```
SELECT 
    x.distinct power_draw_mode_id,
    sum(x.age_in_hours)
FROM
    (SELECT
        *,
        extract(EPOCH FROM age(to_date, from_date))/ 3600 as age_in_hours
    FROM
        your_table
    )x
WHERE
    x.power_draw_mode_id = 2
```